# Setting the location / margin of first node in winforms treeview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I would like to set winforms `treeview` in c# so that I can customize the spacing between top of treeview and first node in it. I couldn't find any property for that.

What is a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I found was to add node without text as first node. If ShowLines is false, then it will look exactly like what I have required.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a 100% certain, but I believe the `Padding` property would put the correct spacing between the first Node inside the `TreeView` and the `TreeView` itself.

So setting the `Padding Top` to like 10px should work.